# Form POST to DynamoDB entry

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a fairly simple challenge.

I've got an HTML form with one field and a submit button. It simply asks for an email address, and when the user hits the submit button, I'd like to somehow get that email address into DynamoDB.

Equivalently, there will be an unsubscribe button, that needs to remove a single email address from DynamoDB.

What is the simplest way of doing this? My current setup includes a Cloudfront distribution, and a static front-end. Ideally, I can avoid API Gateway, and just use Lambda. I don't see a way to POST form data to Lambda however. Would I have to list each Lambda as an origin in Cloudfront?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid API Gateway exactly? You can't send an HTTP request to Lambda directly, you have to use API Gateway for that. You can't "list each Lambda as an origin in Cloudfront" because that would require your Lambda functions to expose an HTTP API, which requires using API Gateway.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid it because it's overkill for my simple use case. It's and hour or more of configuration. I build lots of little websites and apps, and it's nice when I can just code, and not drown in system administration. It's a pain point for me.

Comment: You should look into something like the Serverless framework that manages that stuff for you instead of doing it all manually. https://serverless.com/

Comment: This is another really good framework for spinning up an API with API Gateway and Lambda very quickly: https://github.com/apex/up I think it's easier to use than the Serverless framework, but it's not as popular so you won't find as many tutorials and stuff out there.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of most frameworks. I end up wasting time shopping for frameworks instead of creating the thing I'm trying to create. Thanks for the suggestions, Mark. I may very well realize my ways are strange and misguided someday : )

Answer (score 1):

While API Gateway is simple and straightforward way,

Here is what you can do if you want to avoid API Gateway.

Web (form post) --> S3 (Event Trigger) --> Lambda

Details about the S3 Object will be handed over to Lambda. You can read the form objects and work on the form data.

Hope it helps.